# What is the small metal cover on side of hard drives?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I wonder what is the small metal cover on side of hard drives?

I heard it has a instant data destruction purpose, is that true?

[image: WD 2t whole pic]
Here you can see it on image, just under the disk plate:

[image: Hard disk Hole pic]

Comment: Can you find a photo that isn't copyrighted and perhaps add a circle to indicate clearly the section to which you are referring?

Answer (score 6):

Not all hard disks have them.

It's a dust/pollutants collection sticker that covers a hole in the hard drive casing.

When you're troubleshooting a failing hard drive, you can peel off the sticker and look at the collection of stuff on the inside. If it's a couple of little grayish specs of dust, it's ok. If it's sut-y it may indicate for instance heavy smoking around the PC. If it's a blackish-silvery spray then it's probably a head or axle out of whack, causing the head to scrape very thin scraps of material off the disk's platters. This is often caused by impact trauma like dropping or bumping the disk.

It is certainly not an instant data destruction method. It couldn't be. The data is stored on the hard drive's platters in magnetic patterns and you will need to heavily harm all of the disk platters at the same time (directly physically) or expose it to a powerful magnetic field to instantly destroy a large amount of data. You could say, however, that messing with the sticker in in a polluted environment, while the drive is spinning or doing it wrong in other ways will certainly harm the drive's life expectancy and consequently indeed may destroy data :)

/edit: I found a link with an example: http://www.harddrive-repair.com/hdd-repair-diagnostics.html

Comment: +1 - BTW, think you should include a "Don't try this at home" warning with that link?  ;-)

Comment: If one tries this at home without doing enough research to know that it's not a good idea if one wants to keep using the disk, said one fully deserves to learn that lesson the hard way.
If you replace any equipment though, it can be thoroughly insightful to just open it up and learn how it works instead of just throwing it away. Especially if you have young kids around. It's a great opportunity for a lot of useful stimulations. Tech-savviness, sustainability and general inquisitiveness. Same with cars, watches, laundromats, speakers, bicycles, whatever.